# Add in-app purchase items to next version while current version is under review

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted an App to the AppStore and it's awaiting review. In the meantime I'm working on adding in-app purchases for the next version of the App. To do that I need to add them in iTunes Connect for testing purposes.

I'm unsure if adding the IAP is going to somehow affect the current version (which is currently awaiting review)?

Anyone knows how to handle this situation? Must be quite common?

thank you.

Comment: doesnt belong so i think

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: @matt I don't want to delay approval. Takes time to go through the approval cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app starts with a list of potential IAP items that are passed to the IAP sdk to get the info.  As the new items shouldn't be in the list for the old version of your application, I don't see how they would impact it.   If you retrieve the list from a server, you need to make sure you return the correct list for each version of the app in any case.  If you don't have that logic in place, then things could get confused but it needs to be fixed anyway (imagine users who don't upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

no it wont affect the app review